# Microsoft Intune Device Configuration

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id, mdm, microsoft-intune

I'm working on a project where we need to apply a specific set of configurations and compliance policies to devices associated with the **Intune MDM** (**Mobile Device Management**) platform that are connected to an **Azure AD**. Effectively, we need to be able to authenticate the device to the domain by logging in using domain credentials, but we also want to be able to manage the device using the full suite of Intune options.

We've tried attaching the device to our domain and then enrolling it, and the result is that a number of Intune options (such as "*Restart Device*", "*Run a Malware Scan*" etc.) are all greyed out and cannot be used.

If we try to manually install the Intune client on the device after having attached to the domain, we get an error message saying :

> Device is registered to be managed by MDM service.

We've also tried the reverse, by first installing the Intune client manually on the device and thereupon attaching it to a domain. However, having installed the Intune software manually, we now get an error when trying to attach it to the domain, saying the device is already managed by an organisation.

**My question is :**

Is it possible to attach a Windows 10 device to a domain and subsequently log in using domain credentials, and also install the full Intune client with all available management functions such as *remote restarts* and *Intune policies*? Or can you only have one or the other?

Comment: Does the client have an Office 365 subscription that is using MDM? It sounds like when you domain join the device with the AD user it is picking that up and registering with MDM

Comment: Yes, I believe that may be part of the issue that automatic enrollment is happening with Office 365 MDM. It was our understanding that when creating the environment you need Office 365 as a general management account. Is there a way to specifically disable Office 365 MDM and force it to use Intune?

Answer (score 0):

So as you say, it sounds like users are getting assigned to Office 365 MDM rather than Intune. It should be possible for both to co-exist, but you need Intune to take over management, which according to [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/configmgrdogs/2016/01/04/microsoft-intune-co-existence-with-mdm-for-office-365/) means you need to have an EMS/Intune licence assigned to user at the time you deploy the device. If that's the case then Intune should take over the management role.

Comment: After reviewing my logs, the first thing I did was set up the users and assign intune/EMS licenses to all test users before doing anything with devices. I actually came across that article before and I don't seem to have the button 'MOBILE MANAGEMENT' in the Office 365 portal. I've found this issue with multiple guides as it would seem they are in the process of transferring everything to the new portal which has left broken links and miss matching guides. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you get a user that is not registered for MDM just to test and prove whether this is the issue? If it is, I suspect you might need a support case as beyond that article there isn't much information on co-existance, unless someone with more MDM experience comes along.